# How do I consume a module that utilizes interfaces to extend type?

Tags: typescript

I have a package that exports `dayjs` with plugins:

```
import originalDayjs from 'dayjs';
import relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime.js';

originalDayjs.extend(relativeTime);

export const dayjs = originalDayjs;

export { type ConfigType, type Dayjs, type ManipulateType } from 'dayjs';
export { type Duration } from 'dayjs/plugin/duration.js';
```

Let's call this package `@contra/date`.

The problem is that `dayjs/plugin/relativeTime.js` uses interface to extend the type of `Dayjs`, i.e.

```
import { PluginFunc, ConfigType } from 'dayjs'

declare interface RelativeTimeThreshold {
  l: string
  r?: number
  d?: string
}

declare interface RelativeTimeOptions {
  rounding?: (num: number) => number
  thresholds?: RelativeTimeThreshold[]
}

declare const plugin: PluginFunc<RelativeTimeOptions>
export = plugin

declare module 'dayjs' {
  interface Dayjs {
    fromNow(withoutSuffix?: boolean): string
    from(compared: ConfigType, withoutSuffix?: boolean): string
    toNow(withoutSuffix?: boolean): string
    to(compared: ConfigType, withoutSuffix?: boolean): string
  }
}
```

But the packages that consume `@contra/date` do not see these interface types.

```
import { dayjs } from '@contra/date'

// This produces an error that `.to` is not part of the return type.
dayjs().to(...);
```

I conceptually understand the problem, but I am unsure how to fix it.

It appears that I am able to achieve this by coping the interface into the module itself, but that feels extra.

```
import originalDayjs from 'dayjs';
import relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime.js';

declare module 'dayjs' {
  interface Dayjs {
    from(compared: ConfigType, withoutSuffix?: boolean): string;
    fromNow(withoutSuffix?: boolean): string;
    to(compared: ConfigType, withoutSuffix?: boolean): string;
    toNow(withoutSuffix?: boolean): string;
  }
}

originalDayjs.extend(relativeTime);

export const dayjs = originalDayjs;

export { type ConfigType, type Dayjs, type ManipulateType } from 'dayjs';
export { type Duration } from 'dayjs/plugin/duration.js';
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77477805/edit) the question to include a [mre]? I'd like to help, but reproduction is the first step. You'll need to include everything required for each package — config files such as `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, etc. — steps for compiling — versions of Node.js and npm, etc.

Comment: I suspect that your compiled type definitions don't include the interface extension, but you haven't included that information in the question and without a [mre], it's impossible to determine.